# First (late) answer review

Tags: discussion, review-queues, answers

To do correctly a review of a late answer, I should check existing answers to see if the new answer gives some extra information, right?

But the review window only gives me the question itself and the answer I should review. Why?

Comment: even if it does not give any extra info the part of reviewing wants you to judge the answer itself. What would you do if there was an answer like that but worded differently? Would you say "not good, delete?"

Comment: So for review of answer I do not care if it's a duplicate?

Comment: No, you don't. that's not what the review system on the answers is designed for. It's different with questions as if you know on top of your head it's a duplicate then you can vote-to-close as one but with answers it's different as there is no such checkbox to mark an answer as a duplicate.

Comment: But lets assume that there were a few earlier answers and someone just cut&paste them to the new answer. While reviewing that answer only, it might be accurate, so I would vote up, however it was nothing new provided by that user...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the review of first/late answers you should pay more attention whether the answer doesn't fall in one of the categories in the "flag an answer" box

[image]

If it's **not** any of those then it's most likely fine. Don't worry if it's a duplicate of another answer you're not supposed to handle it from the review queue. It's different from reviewing questions which you can mark as duplicate of another question.

There used to be a system to detect duplicate answers in the 10K review queue (now gone). I am not sure how the duplicate aswers are handled these days but it's nothing to be concerned about while reviewing at this moment.

If you strongly believe that we should be checking all the other answers on the question to make sure the one we are reviewing is not a duplicate ( meaning exact copy ) then feel free to put a feature-request in for this and justify its usefulness.

Comment: I always understood it that when reviewing we should fix all and every problem with a post (same when editing or working the suggested edit queue). Not that I disagree with you on how it should be.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer That's mostly true, but in the Late Answers queue, it's usually either not an answer, spam, very low quality, or fine.