# Should I click on the reviewed question before doing the review work?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

OK.... I landed on this review recently:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/5855999.

Which I failed, having considered the answer a "correct" one, I upvoted then moved away.

It's not a BIG issue, but I want to know if I am meant to actually click on the question and look at it before reviewing. From what I see in the review queue, I have NO WAY of knowing that this answer is actually a copy of the REAL answer, with the added "solved the problem for me". I saw it as a guy proposing a solution.

Was I meant to actually click on the question to see what was done on it beforehand?

I won't ask for the audit to be rolled back or anything, I'm just wondering if I had a chance of noticing this... and if I had, how I could've done it better.

(Side note, this failed audit kicked me off the review queues :(... so I know it's not my first one, but I tried to analyse each of my failed audits.... I just can't figure out how I could've done this differently.)

Comment: Yeah, it's generally a good idea to look at the actual question if you want to avoid situations like this. Personally I think it would be better if all relevant information to reviewing was shown on the review page itself.

Comment: @Grant Winney. Since this was on the "late answers" review, it was shown as a post with no comments/upvotes/nothing. If I SAW the comments I would've reacted differently. At the review time I didn't see the comments.... how was I supposed to know

Comment: @eddie_cat You're right, I felt quickly after starting reviewing it was a good idea to do so. I decided not to because I felt I was "cheating" the system by actually checking if the post WAS a "legit" post or not

Comment: @Julldar it actually was late answers queue. It's generally a good idea to go to the original post in a new tab and see why would anyone answer an old question.

Comment: Nope, definitely not cheating. I have heard a lot of people say that it's actually preferable because if you're looking at the actual question it means you can't be "robo-reviewing." It does make it painfully obvious which reviews are audits, though. :)

Comment: @vba4all thanx for the correction, I hover between both and never remember exactly which one I'm in ;). Corrected ^^

Comment: @eddie_cat. In 2 days, when I can review again, I will definitely make a habit of this then :). thx

Comment: @Grantwinney I can definitely confirm the comments appeared when I made my (wrong) up-vote. Anyway not a big deal, eddie_cat answered me and from now on I'll make a habit of this. Kinda takes the "kick" out of audits though, because this will make them transparent

Comment: Someone should write a user script that lets reviewers know whether they're looking at a real review or an audit, and if it is known-good or known-bad.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi while that would've solved my problem,  I still think it defeats the purpose of audits in the review queue. If someone does that script, audits should simply be taken out, because they won't be failed anymore

Comment: @Julldar Moderators can manually ban users from review, if they see that the users are not reviewing good but are still somehow passing the review audits and sidestepping automatic review bans.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi not contesting that. But if the mods need to manually CHECK someone's reviews, the fact there are "good" audits doesn't change anything, no?

Comment: @pnuts thx :P I don't mind it that much, it's just if these audit questions happen to me I can see someone who gets kicked from reviewing just because of 2-3 weird calls like that. Not my case, but still

Comment: Looking at the original question when you're not sure is part of the work and thought that goes into reviewing. The fact that it makes the audit painfully obvious doesn't mean you're cheating, or that the audit system doesn't work, it just means that you're putting sufficient effort into reviewing, which means you deserve to pass the audit. They're not meant to be difficult challenges, they're just meant to catch roboreviewers and other people who aren't helping.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This looks like one of those posts where the answerer merely copied the text of someone else's answer into a new answer, and then said at the bottom of the new answer "Yep, this works."

This doesn't really help anyone.  It's especially maddening because it actually looks like an answer, until you see their "this works." comment, and simply stating that "this works," rather than "thanks, this code provided by another user works" makes it look like an original answer.

If your spidey sense tingles at all, click the link that takes you to the actual post, and view it in context, along with all of the comments below it that say "Please don't post 'thank you' answers".

Comment: And now your edit makes my other comment obsolete... grrrr :p but yeah, this IS my problem with that review. I was trying to see how, without clicking on the actual question, to pass this audit. I don't think there was a way, unless I have been on the question. Fair enough

Comment: If they didn't want you to look at the original post, they wouldn't provide a link to the original post on the audit.

Comment: yeah, but I still see it as a "cheap" way to simply see the audit itself. I would like to be able to PASS these audits without looking at all of this.... I guess I'll have to trust my spidey sense more often then

Comment: I agree that you should look if there's any doubt, but if there's doubt, then it's not a very good audit.

Answer (score 9):

I think this is just another case of the audit algorithm picking a winner...

Under normal circumstances you shouldn't need to open each review item in a new tab, it isn't cheating to do so, you just shouldn't need to.

Personally I think checking for duplicate answers should be apart of the late answer review, as it is a common enough issue especially with late answers to popular questions, but [apparently that isn't one of the goals of the review at the moment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262097/first-late-answer-review).

Showing the other answers has been suggested before see:
[Showing Whole Threads in Answer-Review Section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148739/showing-whole-threads-in-answer-review-section)
[Review first post / late answers: show other answers as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174445/review-first-post-late-answers-show-other-answers-as-well)

Same issue from last year posted to Meta SE:
[A copy of a good answer as review audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197128/a-copy-of-a-good-answer-as-review-audit)