# Is technical correctness check expected during Late Answer reviews?

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

My understanding is that reviewing answers doesn't require verification from the **technical** correctness perspective - [that's what votes are for](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268849/4495081).

However this appears (to me at least) to be contradicted by my recent audit failure of [this LA review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/12168333).

My technical knowledge of the subject is negligible; I'm in no position to **technically** validate the answer.

The answer quality is not spectacular by SO standards, but it still appears (to me) to be an attempt to answer the question - many accepted/upvoted answers of similar quality level out there.

So I chose "No Action Needed" and flunked the audit.

Is my understanding incorrect? Or am I misinterpreting the audit failure reason? Or something else?

Comment: Audits only check if you are paying attention.  When you don't see that a post was deleted (happened a month ago) and vote "no action required" then the odds of failing the audit hover near 100%, plus or minus 1.

Comment: @HansPassant a 102% chance with a 2% margin of error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed an audit, am I wrong?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278075/failed-an-audit-am-i-wrong); http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272163/should-i-click-on-the-reviewed-question-before-doing-the-review-work is related but not a dupe.

Comment: That was a bad audit.  Hopefully they can fix the audit pool by only using mod deleted content.

Comment: Voted to reopen.  According to Brad's answer, this is a weird special case of flag gaming.

Comment: reopen is wrong, it is a duplicate no matter what flag / vote games were behind. "My technical knowledge of the subject is negligible; I'm in no position to technically validate the answer" => this basically excludes "No Action Needed". If the answer doesn't look worthy deletion the right action is Skip and let others evaluate it further. [There is no shame in using “Skip”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601)

Comment: @gnat how is this question a duplicated of what is essentially a PSA?

Comment: @Braiam No Action Needed with negligible subject knowledge is the road to hell

Comment: @gnat while [I agree](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321934/792066), I don't believe that closing this as duplicated of that is doing a disservice to the wealth of discussion that can be exploited. As you can see, some don't agree with the view you expressed in your comment.

Comment: @HansPassant: It has been widely and repeatedly advised that, when you are working in a review queue, you should pretty much ignore what you see and follow the link to the actual post. *The fact that this is necessary is not a part of how the system is supposed to work; **it is evidence that the system is not working correctly.***  You *should* be able to decide the correct disposition for a review queue item solely from what the review queue shows you. … (Cont’d)

Comment: I flag a fair number of posts, and I see “declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer” often enough that I assume it must be a canned response (from the mod(s) who review flags). *We aren’t supposed to flag answers for being inaccurate or wrong.*  We’re only supposed to flag *low quality* posts: spam, gibberish, offensive, “thanks”, link only, “not an answer to *any* question”, or *maybe* a post that is *flagrantly **not even close*** to being an answer to this question (e.g., a cooking answer to a question about password hash salting).

Comment: (Cont’d) …  The [Guidelines for reviewing Late Answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/195817#180031) say, “It’s important to check if the answer is really relevant to the question. If you don’t know the topic well enough to assess this, avoid actions beyond simple editing for format.” ([Somebody else](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321930/is-technical-correctness-check-expected-during-late-answer-reviews#comment338159_321934 "Braiam") seems to think this is important.) But “avoid actions” means that “No Action Needed” ***is the correct choice***.

Comment: @Scott Saw that as well. Without a canonical question with a clearly winning answer in place it means the matter is actually subjective. Braiam may be right. Conflicting answers. I removed the accepted flag, let the winner be decided by votes!

Comment: @Braiam they disagree with the way you presented it, because your answer failed to communicate point made and much better explained in the dupe target answer (that No Action Needed from lame reviewer deprives more competent ones the chance to educate new users)

Answer (score 32):

So that's an interesting case. Someone flagged it as "very low quality" and reviewers disputed that flag due to [a divided review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11805394). That should have been the end of it.

However, two users had cast delete votes against it. It appears that at that point a third user placed a "not an answer" flag against the answer and then cast the third delete vote. This validated the "not an answer" flag and deleted the post.

That seems at the best questionable and at the worst an attempt at gaming the flag system. As a result, this post became an audit when it shouldn't have been. A moderator would have declined that "not an answer" flag.

Sorry you got hit with this audit, but there's unfortunately nothing I can do about it at this stage. I'll try to make sure this incorrect flagging stops.

Comment: So audit flop (I understand sw is not perfect), no adjustment of my understanding required. That's all I needed. Thx.

Comment: This audit is good. The users downvoted *heavily* this post indicating that it's not useful. They are [expected to do so](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180030/213575).

Comment: @Braiam Users are encouraged to provide feedback if they have an opinion.  They're not required to have a particular opinion.

Comment: @Braiam - You're free to vote based on technical correctness of an answer, but audits should be obvious to any reviewer. The audits for bad content should be gibberish, spam, or obvious non-answers, not things that require technical expertise. Under normal circumstances, this would not have been an audit, because the community disputed the first flag on it and moderators would have declined the second.

Comment: I'm not discussing this, but is obvious that if OP knew a bit of the topic in question he wouldn't have failed the audit.

Comment: Wait, you can validate a flag by casting a delete vote outside of review? That's borked.

Comment: @nathantuggy any time a post is deleted with pending non mod flags they get marked as helpful.

Answer (score -12):

> Is technical correctness check expected during Late Answer reviews?

YES IT IS!

> No Action Needed when this post needs no action from you.
>
> I'm Done is only available if you've done one of the following:
>
> - **Vote up or down to rate the answer's helpfulness**
> - Edit to improve the answer's appearance, clarity, or accuracy
> - Comment to leave constructive feedback for the author, or vote up existing comments
> - Flag to notify the moderators of serious problems
>
> Be sure to leave a comment if you can help the user out, or click Skip
>   if you are not sure and want to go to the next item.

You are supposed to always evaluate answers in the context of the question (for some reason moderators [believe that they should be exempt to this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag#comment156546_286270), but that's beyond the point). You are shown both, the answer and the question this answer is supposed to solve. If the answer is totally misguided, wrong, etc. you should downvote it. As always, there's [no shame in hitting skip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/792066) if you aren't sure.

Also read:

- [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/213575)

Comment: Hm, if this is correct them IMHO the system should be smart enough to only show such reviews to reviewers who have *some* experience on the subject, measured by some decent tag score or a tag badge(s) for the question's tags... Otherwise the review is mostly wasting reviewer's time, since most of the actions should be "skipped" to be correct...

Comment: @DanCornilescu that's what filters are for, use them.

Comment: I can click on no action needed doing nothing to the post.  Also a wrong answer is still an answer.  We have down votes and delete votes to handle those.  The tool tip for that is: this answer seems to be valid.  It does not say it is.

Comment: @NathanOliver no! A post you have no technical knowledge to evaluate should be left to others to review them. You don't have to touch every post you come across in review. I don't.

Comment: I can evaluate a post for post quality.  I can then leave it up to the people in that tag to vote on it accordingly.

Comment: @NathanOliver again, if you cannot assets in a technical ground the quality of something, you cannot say that "it is *good/bad* quality". Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180031 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180030

Comment: If you feel confident enough in your knowledge of the subject matter you're certainly encouraged to provide that feedback when voting, but you are by no means obligated to have a detailed technical understanding of every post you review.  The review system is specifically set up so that the posts can typically be reviewed without requiring detailed domain knowledge.

Comment: @Servy when you say "no action needed" you are basically saying to the system "nobody will find nothing wrong with this post, as is" which isn't accurate. I skip about 60 post a day because I can't, on technical grounds, evaluate them. Is a responsible thing to do.

Comment: @Braiam You shouldn't be upvoting a post if you have no idea of it's technical value.  There will be posts where you can confidently downvote them because they have severe problems that clearly  make them unhelpful.  That said, even if you cannot evaluate whether it is a technically correct answer to the question there are many things that you can do from Review to review the post.

Comment: No no action needed says it seems like an answer aka not flag worthy.  That is all we need to be able to determine.  The people in the tag can then handle voting on it.

Comment: @Braiam The fact that you skip a lot of posts that you can actually review because you don't want to review them is certainly your choice, and you're not harming the system, but no, you do not need to be able to evaluate the technical validity of the post to review it.  If you did, the queue would essentially be useless and should never be used by anyone ever.

Comment: @Braiam Thx for the filters comment! I didn't notice I can also place tags in them...

Comment: @Braiam Also there is nothing in your how to review link that says I need technical knowledge.

Comment: @Servy and neither of them will be complete, compressive actions. If you cannot simply say that "I'm going to edit this answer for better formatting" without knowing that is actually a fork bomb. **If you don't know, tell the system you don't know.**

Comment: @NathanOliver [**"It's important to check if the answer is really relevant to the question. If you don't know the topic well enough to assess this, avoid actions beyond simple editing for format."**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180031/213575)

Comment: Yes **relevent**.  That means the answer is talking about the question.  It has nothing to do with being right or wrong.

Comment: Nothing in what you quoted says **technical**

Comment: @Braiam You don't *need* to know the technical validity of the answer to review it.  That's not what the queue exists to have reviewers do.  Voting on a post without understanding the technical merit would be a problem, but abstaining from voting because you don't have an opinion on its technical value is perfectly fine.  Voting is not the primary purpose of the review queue, just something incidental to do while focusing on the *real* goals of the queue.

Comment: @NathanOliver if I didn't knew you better I would think that you are trying to strawman me. What knowledge is required to have in a programmer site? Remember that that post is faq for all SE, so including "technical" would reduce the faqness of the post. What technical expertise would be necessary to evaluate Community Building posts?

Comment: What I am getting at is the queue is not there to judge the technical correctness of the answer.  It is there to make sure the answer is an answer and not spam, gibberish, rant, abuse.  If you want to gauge the correctness yourself then go ahead but I do not need to know whatever language to determine if a answer is an answer and relevant to the question.  It could be wrong but that is not why the queue is here.  The people in the tag can handle wrong answers.  The queue is here to make sure garbage is not being posted.

Comment: @NathanOliver well, since you are going that way, lets quote someone else... **you**: ["Answers a different question" should be "Flag as VLQ and perhaps comment."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288506/792066) and ["In either queue, if you see an answer that: s wrong, generally a lousy hack, barely addresses the question, or otherwise well below par: Downvote; comment if practical."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/288506/1). How do you plan that reviewers do that?

Comment: @Braiam The is a difference between me [NathanOliver](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver) and the person you are quoting [Nathan Tuggy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4099598/nathan-tuggy).  His words are not mine ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver ups, that was embarrassing. Anyways, that's the current *expected* walk-through of the FP/LA queue. So, do you don't agree with the guidance provided?

Comment: @braiam yes I do.  It is late today so I will bring it to tomorrow but in my opinion the queue should be for getting rid of bad content not wrong content.  flags should also not be used to get rid of wrong content.  That is what we have down votes and delete votes for.  The queues and flags should be used to clean up garbage.

Comment: @Braiam: For clarity, as the main author of that MSO faq-proposed: while I certainly agree that a reviewer in FP/LA should definitely have enough technical savvy to be able to spot, say, a LINQ answer to a Java question, and while I stand by my instructions there that someone spotting a definitely quite bad answer should downvote it, I do not consider that this should imply Skips all the time from everyone without enough expertise in the subject to be quite sure whether an upvote or downvote is really warranted. (1/2)

Comment: @Braiam: (2/2) If there's nothing that stands out, one vote more or less won't make that much difference, and queues that open at 500 rep are not the place for extremely precise technical nitpicking of subtle security bugs or performance implications. Actually, review queues *of any kind* are not the place for that. Technical qualifications are supposed as unspecialized as possible: a Haskell programmer should, >75% of the time, be fine reviewing APL answers. Some answers may be too involved to give a clean pass on without more specific knowledge, but most should be fine as is.

Comment: @Braiam: (I do agree that diamond mods should be willing to put a little more specialized knowledge into checking for non-answers, but that's a pretty low bar to clear, generally, and is far easier to define consistently than "do I know enough to be sure this does not deserve a vote?")

Comment: The voting for this answer is a dead shame.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, no kidding.  I was astonished.  It seems obvious to me that if you have *NO* idea of the technical accuracy of a late answer, and it seems well-written from a grammar/formatting/sentences perspective, you should click "skip."

Comment: "moderators believe that they should be exempt to this" -- this is quite reasonable approach given that there are only a few diamonds and that they handle hundreds flags a day. Of course none of this applies to regular users reviewing the posts in queues - there are tens thousands eligible users and their reviews are limited to 20-40, so one can expect a considerable effort of them to review a particular post, including checking the question if viewing the answer in isolation doesn't let decide...

Comment: ...another pretty important difference is that for regular reviewers Skip is a totally sensible option while for diamond moderators it ain't exactly so