# Bogus documentation item approved — Can it be prevented?

Tags: discussion, documentation

*Please do not meta-effect the question; there's no need.  It is tidily closed as a duplicate.*

I came across C documentation item [Unable to have good values (-16777216 instead to 0) in C (beginner)](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/7422/unable-to-have-good-values-16777216-instead-to-0-in-c-beginner) (may require 10K+ privileges to see it), which is actually a regular question.  The documentation item was submitted at 2016-10-13 14:28:52Z.  There was no explanation of the problem, and it emphatically was not 'documentation'.

The same material was then presented as a question ([Unable to have good values (-16777216 instead to 0) in C (beginner)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40024250) at 2016-10-13 14:46:26.  That question was closed as a duplicate 5 minutes later.  The question did include a little explanation of what was wanted.

My major concern is the review process for the documentation ([review](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/103194?filter-tags=c)).  Two people correctly objected to the material and rejected it.  Three people approved it.

I've deleted the 'documentation' entry.

#### Questions arising:

- Is there a way to stop 1-reputation newcomers from submitting questions as 'documentation'?  Unless rank newcomers are not allowed to submit documentation at all, this may be unavoidable confusion.  (I'd be OK with a low reputation limit on people being allowed to submit documentation — maybe 'must be able to comment on SO', aka 50 points.)
- Is there an appropriate way to chastise those who approved the 'documentation', cancelling any benefit gained from approving that which should not have been approved, and preferably stopping them from approving anything else in Documentation for some period of time?  (Should I have tagged something and asked moderators to intervene instead of using an MSO question?  If so, where should the tag have been applied?)

Comment: maybe submissions should be apart of the removal of new user restrictions which is 10 rep since documentation voting is at 15 rep and documentation comments is already at 50 rep. or even drop it down to the participate in Meta level which is 5 rep

Comment: I kind of like the idea of a minimum rep for proposing changes - users without enough rep could still make topic requests and improvement requests.

Comment: This looks like a job for a "That looks like a question, would you like to post it on the main site instead?" script.

Comment: Just had similar example with http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/103761 How to people approved that is beyond me.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar did you flag one of their posts to assign a review ban?

Comment: @Braiam Nope. I wasn't sure what is proper thing to do...

Comment: The reviewers clearly didn't scroll to the end. `Please help` should be a huge red flag here ;)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

- If there is a textbox on The Internet, someone will eventually type a programming question into it. We've seen programming questions posted to the *gardening* site.
- Yeah. I review-banned the folks who approved that for a week with a message. Jarrod's been working on audits and bans; should have some pretty beefy checks in place shortly.

Comment: Recmmended autits: use question the body of a question posted to the site; copy documentation from another tag and post it. UI fixes: don't put a textbox for 1 rep users on documentation.

Comment: I've seen a Java programming question being posted on a travel booking site. I ended up laughing into a facepalm.

Comment: Please include audits where content is directly copy-pasted from MSDN or Wikipedia.

Comment: Why are users with 100 reputation able to review this stuff in the first place? How could it possibly be a good idea to put that much trust in those users?

Comment: Perhaps we should initially allow reviews by gold badge holders in that tag, after some timeout we go to silver badge holders, then bronze and then everybody. This would give those we trust more first dibs on approving/rejecting things.

Comment: @RobertLongson why not then move to rep...

Comment: @Braiam Because rep isn't tag-specific, but documentation is related to one specific subject.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes at least they have the basic knowhow of SE, unlike the 1 rep population.

Comment: Can you please look at another question that has been approved by some reviewers (I don't know what would be appropriate channel to notify about bad reviews) -  http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/103761

Comment: @Gimby go to Java, learn Java, drink Java?

Comment: @Braiam there's a feature request to add that kind of audit [here](/q/336963).

Comment: Actually, I kind of want to see who had the _brilliance_ to post their programming question on [gardening.se].

Comment: @StephenLeppik people clicks random link and doesn't notice how the entire theme changed https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278592/213575

Answer (score 24):

The review system is rotten.

Given you are a *specialist*, the last thing in this life you would likely do is to sit behind a computer screen and review some strange ideas someone had a fancy to express.

Which is leaving the review queue to *enthusiasts* eager to earn *reputation points.* So you cannot expect anything useful from the review system, save for barring obvious obscenity and spam. There was a topic here on Meta while ago, [where reviewers fiercely **demanded the right to be ignorant in the technical matters**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321930/is-technical-correctness-check-expected-during-late-answer-reviews), and were **granted** that right by the public opinion (watch the voting). So you can tell that your case is not an exception but a rule.

And that "beefy" *manual* checks promised in the other answer is a drop in the ocean. The system will remain the same.

Comment: Agreed. A few nitpicks: reviews usually don't give reputation. In Documentation they don't even give progress towards a badge (thank goodness!) As for technical knowledge... it's not always needed. As an extreme example, a spam answer doesn't require knowledge about the question - just flag and move on. But if a review queue allows voting, then yes, the reviewer should only vote if they understand the post.

Comment: ...review doesn't earn you rep.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I think YCS is a "I'll scratch your back if you scratch mine" kind of.

Comment: Of course, the linked meta post was about the Late Answers review queue, which carries different requirements than the Documentation review queue. I'd hoped that the developers would have put a bit more thought into the Documentation review, but the fact is that they purposefully *want* inexperienced people to contribute to Documentation. Thus, having them review other inexperienced people's contributions makes sense... in some universe, apparently.

Comment: *"Which is leaving the review queue to enthusiasts eager to earn reputation points."* - This is the crux of the problem.  IMO, documentation reputation and Q & A reputation need to be separated.  You should not be able to earn points on one side for the other side.