# Should bad quality questions be given a grace period to be improved rather than deleted outright?

Tags: discussion

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105055/my-programming-language-is-c

It was a badly asked and badly formatted question with a link to image of code, instead of text

i.e. have a hint provided as to how to improve question and if not fixed, deleted in an appropriate amount of time.

Comment: How do you propose to rehabilitate "THIS GIVE ERROR HOW TO RESOLE [sic]"?

Comment: The asker had a compile error.  Look at the error through more experience eyes, reform question as if you had it and didn't know how to solve.  i.e. "I coded a summation example in good faith but compiler gives me error X.  Why?"

Comment: @Dennis: Is the core question so valuable to the site that you are prepared to not only reproduce the code character for character in text, but also attempt to compile it and reproduce the compiler error and formulate a coherent question in place of... whatever that's there?

Comment: _Should bad quality questions be given a grace period to be improved rather than deleted outright?_ No. You have as long as you are alive to get the post right **before** you post. You can check **everything** before you post. It is most certainly not recommend to post a very poor question _and then_ edited into shape.

Comment: @BoltClock, I suppose it is not. Part of me was wondering more so in line of "will poor remain poor because no one taught them to be rich?". That is, there is someone who has no good mastery of English, or Computer Science, or how Internet forums typically work, attempts to ask a question... badly.  Who will show them how to improve?  If no one does this, they will remain incompetent. Via moderation like this, SO is enforcing a minimum cost of entry to where the incompetent are essentially forced out until they either forced to improve on their own if they can figure out how, or they give up

Comment: @Dennis: We do expect at least some degree of cooperation and competence from the user, the absolute least of which is to take some time to read through [ask] that's presented to every user asking a question for the first time. If they won't even do that, and judging by what is seen here it's extremely likely they didn't bother to do so, then the odds that they'll understand, let alone heed any advice from real people are extremely slim.

Comment: @Dennis: As for command in English, this is an English-language site after all, and all Q&A and documentation is in English. We cannot provide ESL tuition for everyone, or localize the site for every language imaginable, and language barriers are recognizably difficult to overcome for both parties involved. It's an unfortunate reality that we can't help everyone.

Comment: There was nothing that anyone was going to do that would save that question.

Comment: @CodyGray .. it *was* going to be me....

Comment: It would not have been possible. Or at least, not *reasonably* possible. You would have had to retype the entire thing, including transcribing the code from the image into the question box. Then what would we have had? You would have spent a *lot* of time on this, and all for what? There are better things you could have been doing, not the least of which is answering questions that were presented in a reasonable manner.

Comment: the core of the "answer" I expected would be that the asker had a compile error.. fixing that error & making code work to me would have been an acceptable answer, unless the asker was going after something totally different.  To me it was a case of "I don't know what's wrong, but it hurts, fix it" -> "there, it's fixed & here's what was wrong"

Comment: *I don't know what's wrong* - But you have to know what's wrong, the site rules require it for debugging questions. You need to at least be able to give an error code or say where the issue is occurring.

Comment: why is there an upvote?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There usually is a grace period before deletion for these questions. A 10k user can only vote to delete a question that is at least two days old, and 20k users can only vote to delete something younger than that if it hits a -3 vote threshold.

Moderators tend to hold off on immediate deletion of questions if there is any hope at all for them to be edited into a good, on topic question. We may delete wildly off topic questions ("can't log in to facebook", "why is my girlfriend cheating on me", etc.) as soon as we see them, though.

However, sometimes questions just are so bad or are causing so much trouble via flags that we'll step in and delete them early. That seems to be the case here, and odds are there isn't much that could be done to save that question.

Comment: Things must be bad when you're posting on SO asking programmers _why is my girlfriend cheating on me_.

Comment: @Bugs - There are currently 690 deleted posts on SO containing the word "girlfriend", some quite disturbing in nature. If there is a text box on the Internet, eventually people will write pretty much anything into it.

Comment: @BradLarson I thought it was [_"If there is a textbox on The Internet, someone will eventually type a programming question into it."_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336273/4639281).

Comment: @TinyGiant Shog was using context to form that phrase.

Comment: Some of those posts are pretty much "I don't want to live anymore..." and some are just "how do I find a new one..." - some are just junk. @Braiam mods can contact the CM team where things can't be handled by mods alone (or even should)... there's even a custom flag we can use to raise it to the CM team: "A user has expressed suicidal thoughts."... - thankfully, it rarely happens.

Comment: I feel suicidal every time a meta post appears about elitist, mob downvoting.  After re-reading such posts and comments, I move on to homicidal.  Luckily, there is beer as a cure.

Comment: @Braiam I was using that phrase to be funny.

Comment: "sometimes questions just are so bad or are causing so much trouble via flags that we'll step in and delete them early" Where's the threshold for this? I flagged such oh-my-god-this-is-so-bad-it-hurts-my-eyes questions several times (with a "rude or abusive" flag + a comment explaining my reasoning when I felt like superheavy ordinance was warranted) and all of those flags got declined with the questions not being deleted on sight.

Comment: @dorukayhan - Spam or offensive flags should only be used for content that is actually spam or offensive. There already is a path for community review of extremely low quality questions via "very low quality" flags, so we're likely to decline custom moderator flags asking for immediate deletion due to quality and direct you to use one of those instead. We might sometimes decide to delete a question ourselves, but the use of moderators as deletion proxies doesn't scale, which is why we decline many of these custom flags and direct people to "very low quality" instead.

Comment: Is there a dating/relationships site where I can post my C++ questions?

Answer (score 3):

Think of this situation like [triage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triage).  For instance,

- There are questions which will be bad regardless of the edits made to it.
- There are questions which will be good regardless of the edits made to it.
- There are questions which edits will make a positive difference for it if applied.

This is one of those cases that the question will always be bad.  Let's walk through how.

---

First, this is the only thing *written* in the question:

> THIS GIVE ERROR HOW TO RESOLE PLEASE EXPLAI IT EASILY BECAUSE I AM A NEW PROGRAMMER

Ignoring the caps, here's what we know:

- The code gives an error
- They don't understand what the error actually *is*
- They want us to explain what the error is

That's closeable as "too broad" on any given day *by itself*.

Now, to the code they "attached".  This is reproduced as closely as I can do the original format:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main( )

{
int a, b, c, sum ;
printf ( "\nEnter any three numbers " ) ;
scanf ( "%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c ) ;
sum = calsum ( a, b, c) ;
printf ( "\nSum = %d", sum );
}
calsum( x, y, z )
int x, y, z ;
{
int d;
d = x + y + z;
return ( d );
}
```

Doesn't look like it's going to compile which means this is a compilation error, and a fairly basic one at that.  Most editors would inform you of this and the compiler would also tell you what's going on.  I'll admit though that I get different errors from this code than I would from the OP, but that doesn't mean that the question is *redeemable* because of it.

Questions should get some kind of grace period to improve themselves, which is what closing it does.  This question *can't* be improved regardless of who edits it.

Comment: putting it this way, the question becomes more so "explain how to debug my program" and it is not clear where the asker's knowledge gaps are.  It is possible however to make the program compile and explain what caused it to not compile. It is not clear whether doing so will help, since the knowledge gaps may be too broad.

Comment: @Dennis:  No, there's nothing wrong with knowledge gaps.  This is why questions are asked at all.  The issue here is that there could be any number of issues with their code and they're effectively asking us to fix it.  That's simply too broad.

Answer (score 2):

There *are* tools available to give questions that are salvageable a chance to be improved.  If a question is problematic, it's important that it is *always* closed as quickly as possible, but while the question is closed, the question author (and others) are then able to improve the question, hopefully to the point that it can be reopened.  It's *possible*, but intentionally made rather difficult, to delete a question shortly after it has been closed.

Questions are only deleted when it's been determined that they are not going to be salvaged into good questions (either because they can't be, or because they clearly aren't going to be).  Privileged users or moderators can delete recently closed questions, under some circumstances, but it's deliberately designed to ensure that only *really* bad questions, questions that have no shot at all of being improved, actually get deleted this way.  Questions that have been closed for a while and still haven't been improved eventually become easier to be deleted (the requirements are lowered), and eventually it reaches a point where questions that meet certain criteria are automatically deleted, because the question author has demonstrated a lack of ability or interest in fixing the question.

See [the faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) for specifics on the various means of deletion for posts.

Comment: well I could argue that this particular one could have been improved to a salvageable point.  i.e. converted to text & reflected the problem more clearly.  It was an answerable question in my point of view, even though the quality of question was quite poor.

Comment: @Dennis Just posting the code as text, alone, wouldn't make the question acceptable.  The question still doesn't explain what the code is supposed to do, why it doesn't work, what error it's getting, what research they've done into what that error message means, and why that hasn't helped them solve the problem, etc.  This is a question that would fall into the bucket of, "while it's technically possible for a person to turn this into an acceptable question, the odds that this particular user actually will are essentially zero."  Hence why it was deleted.  At least that's my guess.

Comment: @Dennis The post was deleted by me. The question was IN ALL CAPS and was getting a few comments asking the op to REFRAIN FROM USING CAPS, hence I took the extreme step. I'm sorry if I deleted it whilst you were editing it, but IMO, I'm sure that even if it was converted to code, the post would have been closed as off topic for no MCVE. As Servy said, it was a real bad question.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that one.  It was too bad to live, in multiple ways:(

Comment: Questions aren't *only* deleted because of that.  I've seen very decent duplicates deleted just because they were duplicates.

Comment: @BhargavRao:  I would argue that there *is* an MVCE, since the picture includes both the code and the error.  However, the decision seems fine since there's really not much to redeem with it.

Comment: @Makoto, Ah, my bad. Looks like the commented part is the error, I thought it was a part of the code. (Sorry for my technical inability to grasp that immediately).

Comment: @Makoto In that case the question isn't *useful*, and can't (or isn't going to) be made to be useful, hence the deletion.  The fact that the question *would* have been a useful question if it hadn't already been asked before doesn't change the fact that it *has* been asked before, and is therefore not useful.

Answer (score -5):

If you're really interested in improving a deleted question, there's an excellent tool for that: Post a new question.

I don't really see the point of giving every single question a chance, no matter how bad it is. Better to focus on good (or at least not crappy) questions.

Comment: Two bad questions is worse than one bad question.

Comment: Yes? If one question gets deleted and you post a new (bad) question you only have one bad question.

Comment: No, it's still two.  Both still get attention in that they're meant to be moderated.