# What happens when I flag an unwelcoming comment in a blatantly poor question?

Tags: discussion, moderators, comment-flags, welcoming, code-of-conduct

Say that I flagged an [unwelcoming comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313754/165773) in a blatantly poor question and a moderator agreed - what next?

I would like to roughly figure how things would typically go after my flag is handled (I know that there can be variations depending on specific context and on personal judgement of a moderator, but still).

To start with, would a moderator be expected to dig into comments history of the flagged user? They sure can do this if they want to, but what if they don't? If a moderator just doesn't have time at the moment, could they rely on some sort of automatic system that would warn / raise a flag in case the flagged user has a history of troublesome commenting patterns?

I also would like to better understand the consequences if a moderator decides to warn or suspend a flagged user. If this user wants to learn about what they did wrong, what would their options be? Would they have to go to Meta and ask about their past deleted comments or there will be some other way available to them to learn ([related feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371385/839601))?

Last, but not least, what about this blatantly bad question where I flagged that comment? Would it be okay for a moderator to close / delete it to prevent further piling up of unfriendly comments, or are they expected to wait until regular 3K / 10K / 20K users take care of it?

Comment: I was gonna write a standard-type explanatory answer upon reading the title and first paragraph, but then I realized it's from you and you probably want something more in depth then that.

Comment: @Magisch thanks, you got it right, I more or less understand how system was supposed to work with the old-fashioned rude/abusive flags but we seem to be getting new flags and new code of conduct and I wonder what impact these changes are going to have on moderators

Comment: Isn't there an automated mod-flag when a user has x-amount/percent comment flags?

Comment: @AndréKool I think there is a system flag for rude comments, but it is _very_ unlikely that there is one for "no longer needed" ones. If you think of it, what would moderator tell user who got 100 no-longer needed flags, how it can be reason to worry (for the sake of precision, sometimes there _can_ be reason to worry but automatic system would hardly be able to tell this)

Comment: ...in particular I wonder how system would adapt to new planned type of flag [described in more details here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313552/165773)

Comment: So, was it _"not welcoming enough"_ or just _"rude"_? Since when it not being "welcoming" a flaggable offense? What _is_ "welcoming"? I mean, I'm not being "welcoming" with this comment, but there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @Cerbrus see my prior comment, it refers to the post from SE employee explaining their plan to add this kind of flag

Comment: [related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389250/839601)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> I flagged an unwelcoming comment in a blatantly poor question and say, moderator agreed - what next?

We delete the comment. You get a helpful flag. (You can celebrate if you hit a milestone like 500 helpful flags (Marshal badge)).

> how things would typically go after my flag is handled ... would moderator be expected to dig into comments history of the flagged user?

Typically the comment flag queue is large, and we go through each of the rude/abusive flags one at a time. Therefore we won't be digging into the history. However, if we find a suspicious user (which I can't mention who is), we will immediately dig into their history. It all depends on the wording of the rude comment. If it is extremely rude, we immediately warn the user. If the comment has been very recent (<3 minutes), it indicates that the user is currently going on a rude comment spree, so we jump to a small 1 day or a 1 week suspension (this is if and only if they are being rude in the immediate present, if it's a few minutes old, and is blatantly rude/abusive, we just warn them).

The entire answer is written keeping rude/abusive flags in mind. If you flag it as No longer needed, then it's totally upto the moderator to dig into it and follow up. However, while handling the NLN flags, if we see a very rude comment, we follow the same procedure as explained in the previous paragraph.

> Say, if a moderator just doesn't have time ... could they rely on some sort of automatic system

For starters, if a moderator doesn't have time, they won't handle it. We are usually aware that handling a particular incident takes x amount of time, and we handle it only if we have that much amount of time. (If the flag is No longer needed, and is rude, we skip it, if we don't have the time to check for rude comments).

Now, getting back to the normal handling of comments. We don't dig into the history of each and every user who has got a comment of theirs flagged as rude. We do rely a lot on the [Possible Comment Abuse flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284053/community-deletion-of-comments-should-raise-a-moderator-flag). The PCA flag is raised when a number of comments of a user are flagged as rude and are deleted consequently. This is a very good and handy tool for moderators as we catch the repeat offenders. The PCA flag takes the past n days into consideration, so we can see if a user has been rude in the past few days as well.

> consequences if moderator decides to warn or suspend flagged user. If this user would want to learn about what they did wrong, what would be their options?

If the moderator decides to warn:

1. They get a big fat inbox notification with a "Moderator Private Message" at the top and a reasoning as to why they were warned/suspended.
2. They get an email to the associated mail ID. If there's no attached mail ID, they won't get one.

This message is sent from the Stack Overflow Moderator Team and is visible to all the diamond users on the site. The template [used for the message is mentioned in Brad's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371400/4099593). On receiving the message, the user can either:

1. Reply back to the private message. They can only do it once (some people reply with a "what" and lose their chance of having a constructive conversation). They can ask for clarification regarding the warning/suspension. The moderators can either choose to reply or refrain. If they reply, the user gets another chance to reply.
2. Contact Stack Exchange directly using the /contact page and contest their private message.

If the user wants to learn, they can use either of these options. They can apologize for the issue if they admit to it, and ask for clarifications on how to improve. (They can post on meta asking for tips, but that is not encouraged as it's airing their own dirty laundry).

> Would they have to go to meta and ask about their past deleted comments or there will be some other way available to them to learn?

The meta step is unnecessary. They can clearly use the reply option on their warning message to ask for their rude comments. (I usually attach a list of their comments along with the warning/suspension, so that they won't need to ask for them). They can also write to Stack Exchange directly asking for the rude comments for which they were warned/suspended.

> what about this blatantly bad question that has got my comment flag? Would it be okay for moderator to close / delete it

We immediately close the bad questions when we see it. Even if a post does not have any rude comments, and we see that it's bad, we close it.

The deletion part is where I'm not sure, as moderator deletions are not reversible by 10k users. I usually [delete bad questions if I'm sure that they won't be improved.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352248/4099593) (and I'm pretty sure most moderators do). However it is left to you all (the community) to decide if it's okay for moderators to delete blatantly off topic posts, without waiting for the OP to update, if they've been rude.

Comment: This second paragraph has confused me no end... so a rude comment can get you suspended if caught straight away... but if it takes a few minutes for it to get picked up, the same comment will only get you a warning... What!? Is there a piece of the puzzle i'm missing?

Comment: @NickCardoso quick (and I guess usually brief) suspension is to prevent "rude comment spree" mentioned in that very paragraph. Its purpose is not so much to punish user but to cool down and prevent them from slipping into deeper trouble

Comment: Wouldn't a warning have the same effect? Instead of a week suspension just because they got flagged 4 minutes faster...

Comment: @NickCardoso suspension seems safer. If one is in the rage warning has a risk of having opposite effect and getting them angrier, it is probably more reliable to just give them some time to cool off

Comment: ...hey and I just noticed you mention week suspension, my understanding is moderators can use shorter suspensions, like a day or even less @NickCardoso

Comment: I was just referring to the answer text - "a small 1 day or a 1 week suspension"

Comment: I see @NickCardoso - sorry I didn't notice this part in the answer. Hope that first time outrages are typically handled with 1 day while week suspension is reserved for repeat cases (if user already had 1 day suspension in the past and slipped into rage again)

Comment: @NickCardoso, the issue is that the private messages go into the same inbox as the comments. Given that it's mostly new users who become extremely rude, they are also more likely to ignore the inbox notification, because they assume that it's from their post and not a private message. Therefore when a heated argument  going on currently we jump to a suspension (some users have replied to a later suspension, after a warning, that they didn't see the warning).

Comment: Now, the reason why I mentioned 1 week is because the mod message automatically starts off with 1 week, and we need to edit it to make it 1 day (takes 30 seconds). Some moderators, depending on the situation, do not wait to edit the message, and directly suspend, which is when it becomes 1 week (I've done that twice, one time where a user was adding rude comments and vandalizing their post and I wasn't as fast as them in reverting). All in all, it's mostly a judgement call on the handling moderator's part (whether to go with a warning, 1 day suspension or a 7 day suspension).

Comment: '*They get a big fat inbox notification with a "Moderator Private Message" at the top and a reasoning as to why they were warned/suspended.*' - This can be a bit sketchy from my personal experience. It didn't show up for me and I was confused for quite a while.

Comment: Why is there not yet a way to cast a non-binding deletion flag for moderators? Something where, "I agree this should be deleted", but not enough that says this should be deleted right now. That's the benefit for us 10/20k users: We can rely on others to confirm our suspicious. Moderators do not have this benefit.

Comment: _...(which I can't mention who is)..._: this remind me of "Who's on first" from Abbott & Costello