# Be nice, be nice, be nice, yes, but what if the question is horrifically egregiously bad?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, welcoming, behavior

So yes, it is being drummed into us to always be nice, but good lord almighty, what to do when you run into horrific, terrible, and just plain lazy homework dump questions, questions such as this quickly closed and deleted gem:

[image]

Link: [Homework specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499018/homework-specification)

Maybe it's me (probably it's me), but how to respond nicely to the likes of this? OK, perhaps T.J. Crowder's comment was in fact nice and informative, and my little, "at least you're being upfront, that this is a homework dump, plain and simple" wasn't, but gosh almighty, it. is. so. darn. hard.

To all the mods who have to handle my comments -- I'm sorry. I'm trying, but it's so hard. If I get banned for this, all I can say is it's been a nice ride while it lasted.

Comment: Why respond at all to such a question?

Comment: Your close-vote/delete-vote/down-vote should be response enough.

Comment: related: [What happens when I flag an unwelcoming comment in a blatantly poor question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372113/839601) "We immediately close the bad questions when we see it. Even if a post does not have any rude comments, and we see that it's bad, we close it..."

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: I keep asking myself that very question. All I can say is, it's hard for me not to. Maybe I should take this up with my therapist.

Comment: Related: [*But seriously. How to be nice when trying to say the code is crap?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367789/2751851)

Comment: @duplode: thanks for the link. I should start a Facebook page: United SO Ranters

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I'm more in favor of ASOR (Anonymous SO Ranters).

Comment: since the homework dump is tagged java and you have badge in this tag you would probably benefit of [this recently proposed feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374490/839601): "show the viewer [this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNgd5.png)... Upon submission, the question will be immediately deleted..."

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I heard Twitter is a good place for this too...

Comment: Well, surely what you really want is a simple and harmless way to ensure this user never comes back again.  Like, erm, reset the view counter back to 1 :)  There is some hope in [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374490/17034).

Comment: That question is not near the lowest, not when compared to, say,  this:https://stackoverflow.com/q/52486064/758133  'I typed lines of code that I don't understand and they somehow formed up into a working bubble-sort program.  Now I want you to explain it so that I can hand it in and so that my prof thinks I actually know something and did some actual work'.  At least the homework vamp linked/shown in this Q. admitted it was homework.

Comment: lol, T.J. Crowder's canned response is great...

Comment: Page has been deleted; what did T.J. Crowder say? I'm curious!

Comment: Don't be the hero that SO deserves, be the hero that SO needs right now.

Comment: @MCEmperor: "Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], look around, and read through the [help], in particular [ask]? Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc.**, and give it a try. If you run into a *specific* problem, research it thoroughly, [search thoroughly here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. People will be glad to help."

Comment: Be neither nice nor not nice. Be informative. "This is a homework copy/paste which is not a good question for this site."

Comment: also related  [Close voters call to arms: let's make this September welcoming](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373680/839601) "How about we help site newcomers learn to properly ask questions by spending few minutes in review queue and voting to close inappropriate ones more quickly..."

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, any USOR merch? Mug? Tee Shirt? Pins?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a rant, the author himself admits he doesn't need an answer and only tries to blow off steam.

Comment: There is no CoC against dumping homework. http://dilbert.com/strip/2018-09-26

Comment: I'm voting to keep it open since Hover needs some support/advice to keep the tongue in check while continuing to improve SO.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Man, I would create FB profile just to join that group, or even better, let's have one SO with "be nice" policy and one without it ...

Comment: For what it's worth, I feel your pain too. The sheer audacity of that title alone...

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev oh it's worse than that  The author is aditting that s/he DOES need an answer but experience has shown him/her that none will be forthcoming;(

Comment: @TadeuszKopec yes, there is: you are supposed to 'Be nice'.  Trying to get others to do work for no wages is not nice.  Wars have been fought over the issue and, mostly, there is a concensus that it's a bad thing.

Comment: @MartinJames You didn't follow the Dilbert link, did you?

Comment: You be nice, it's swine before pearls and don't you forget it.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec Dilbert?  Oh, in that case... :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What if they COULD google their question in 5 seconds?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371347/what-if-they-could-google-their-question-in-5-seconds)

Comment: I like http://idownvotedbecau.se/ for bad questions - in this case, http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ because there appears to have been no effort to solve the problem.

Comment: You of all people ask that? This young padawan is surprised. I always looked up to old Obi van Eel. Because I learned from you to downvote, close vote... Maybe drop a polite but clear comment. To then move on. Well, maybe come back to delete vote.

Comment: At least that question wasn't titled "Please give the correct answer now" like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522342/please-give-the-correct-answer-now-related-to-graph

Comment: @m69 Is there a way to get an image for <10k?

Comment: @EJoshuaS I'm <10k myself. The question was on hold but visible when I commented.

Comment: " I'm sorry. I'm trying, but it's so hard. " | Keep on trying.. We'll never satisfied everyone in the world anyway.. || What I like? You did NOT give up.. Keep trying.. I'm on a mission to make this planet greener/bluer.. And not shedding blood (to catch a fight/being nice while it was harsh) in softcopy.. is.. a VERY good start. | Keep it up. Chayox2 !!    / (^_^)   || p/s : Brownish/Reddish home planet is NOT livable. Period.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I was angry so I didn't check your later responses to know that you didn't delete my question. I'm sorry for my rash act. BTW do you know how to find my deleted questions here? I want to check how and why the question get deleted so fast.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels You will always be nice no matter what situation/people you are facing if you are truly nice people, even they are bad. Very few people can be truly nice (not for me), may be there are genetics factors. Anyway  I  hope  that administration jobs are done by nicer people.

Comment: see also: [A prime example of the culture issue facing new users of the site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389250/839601)

Comment: Easy: You just need to be "horrifically egregiously" nice.  So nice that the average person would want to vomit.  (But don't help him.)  :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing)

Answer (score 174, accepted):

> Maybe it's me (probably it's me), but how to respond nicely to the likes of this?

You don't. You downvote and vote to close, then move on.

Comment: Of course you're right and I'm just ranting, but damn it, sometimes a rant feels good

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels afaik, using catharsis to deal with anger and disgust isn't recommendable, since it only makes you feel angrier and more disgust.

Comment: @Braiam: I disagree. I'm already feeling better after this rant

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: I am a moderator, and I upvoted your comment.

Comment: I feel better too.  It's good that someone fires back occasionally, else our pathetic little army of curators would be completely overrun by the hordes of zombie deadbeats:(

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: if i get annoyed with what i see posted on stackoverflow I go check out Quora. then i feel better about SO right away.

Answer (score 57):

This is an unfortunate Catch-22 in that here we have a perfectly earnest and forthright campaign to make us aware of being more nice to Stack Overflow users, and those users turn around on us and do something like *that*.

Here's the way I see it.

**Being nice doesn't mean responding to *every* question.  It means knowing when to hold your tongue.**

A lot of the unpleasantness comes from how we react to questions like this.  Let me assure you I had the same visceral reaction to this question, like many others like it - it clearly shouldn't exist and yet somehow, *we're* rude or mean or bullies by telling them this fact.

I also feel like comments in reference to the above are a waste of time period.  T.J. made a valiant effort but seriously, there's no point since those kinds of users are **not** here to listen.

So don't comment.  Don't say anything.  Downvote them.  Move on with your life.  They're going to keep whining but it doesn't change the fact that they're not the kind of user we're ***ever*** going to support here.

Comment: This is the part of the "be nice" policy that I will never be in line with:  "and yet somehow, we're rude or mean or bullies by telling them this fact".  I get not being unreasonably harsh.  I get always preferring pleasant over prickish.  But if they're lazy and trying to score a free code, they need to be called on it.  And I don't mind being the one, whether it's deemed nice or not.

Comment: @DonBoitnott I would think having your question anonymously discarded within a few minutes sends a pretty strong signal, perhaps one that’s stronger than angry reactionary comments. You can get into a spat with specific people about specific comments and in the end feel vindicated because “it’s those assholes”. Whereas a swift close-and-delete gives you little to hang your hat on besides yourself.

Comment: The issue with this is that we don't know for sure that the user falls within your category of "those kind of users" that don't listen to feedback (unless I'm missing something that has been deleted). Sure, there are some indications (like the lazy copy-paste and no attempt to follow SO guidelines), but what if that user doesn't mind improving his question? If you downvote that question without responding, and the question doesn't get closed, the user won't learn anything from it. I think T.J. Crowder's comment is a good solution, and certainly not pointless.

Comment: @g00glen00b Indeed, we don't know what kind of user a user is. But we also don't typically have the time and resources to figure it out on a case by case basis. Users will have to learn themselves how to be _that kind of_ user. We're already giving them enough automated hints and guides, we can't handhold everyone. I think such canned responses should be improved by the system, there shouldn't be a need for everyone to reinvent that wheel individually.

Comment: @deceze You're right, having to justify every DV with a comment will slow down the moderation progress. But you also have to realize that this is one of the reasons why users feel unwelcome (it was according to [this blogpost from a user](https://kristofk.com/response-to-stack-overflow-being-unwelcoming/)). Does that mean it's justified to be unwelcome in these cases?

Comment: @g00glen00b I agree that *misunderstanding downvotes* is a big reason why people feel "unwelcome". That is something SO needs to fix by better UI/UX. For example with "you have just received your first downvote, here's what this might mean…" messages or such. Let's work on discussing _that_. Let's not waste our resources explaining this again and again individually.

Comment: @deceze You're right, such a feature would be great, and would be a good answer to address these situations.

Comment: @g00glen00b (and everybody) but until we have such a feature, let's comment with http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ so they at least have an indication of where they downvotes came from. They may not realize we even expect them to put effort into their questions until they feel the bite of downvotes (yes, there is the tour, but in this day and age, people are experts at tuning things out.)

Comment: @NH.:  **No. I _refuse_ to use that site on principle.** It was intended to help but it just *doesn't*.

Comment: @Makoto, what principle? I find it helpful when I receive downvote reasons from there...

Comment: @NH.:  Comments aren't useful to communicate instruction or guidance.  They're useful for commentation, which is the same principle as "backseat driving" or "armchair management".  You can feel like you're helping without really doing much of anything worth any value.

Comment: @Makoto and here you are using comments for guidance. Does that strike you as ironic?

Comment: @NH. FWIW, the comment was a counter-argument to your own, which is not that much of an issue in itself. Plus, this is Meta, so the practical purpose of comments is slightly different.

Comment: @NH. Regarding idownvotedbecau.se comments, those make some users bite back, and might get flagged as unkind as well. If you're in for providing feedback, not even that link is ideal.

Comment: @NH. "I downvoted because..." is a fairly aggressive statement, and that's hard to get away from when it's literally in the text of the link you're using. Downvotes *are* often taken personally, so saying you downvoted is likely to be taken as a personal attack. Roughly the same applies to "I'm voting to close this..." (so I guess it's fine then...). It's much more neutral to say "you may be receiving downvotes because..." or "questions that {do X} are often not received well because..." or asking them to improve their question (if possible).

Answer (score 40):

What we need, is not always what we want.

What the students wants, is for someone to do their homework for them.
What the student needs, is an explanation why they should at least *try* to solve their own homework.

(Just to be clear on this - it's OK to ask for *help* with homework. Even the best students get stuck from time to time, and there's no shame in asking for help after one has tried hard. The problem is students dumping their homework assignments without even trying.)

Fortunately, an explanation on why they should try for themselves is available on Stack Exchange: [an open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/31456).

Giving them the solution to their homework isn't "nice" - it's nasty that's disguised as nice. It's like giving them candy, knowing full well they won't brush their teeth, and have cavities later.

So - downvote and close-vote. And if, after that, you still feel a need to say something.... then link them to that open letter on Software Engineering Stack Exchange. Hopefully that will give you the satisfaction that the student has been sufficiently told to work a bit harder.

Comment: This is an extremely well-thought and philosophical answer. It has certain potential to inspire changes in the Help Centre and a Theory of Moderation.

Comment: About "dumping their homework assignments without even trying": I would argue that (especially) non-native English speakers may have actually tried but do not yet really know how to formulate a specific question about it (and thus end up only copy pasting it). Therefor asking which part they don't understand, what they've tried and where they got stuck might help them understand the down votes.

Answer (score 29):

I’m sure you’ve heard of the term shadowban? A shadowbanned user doesn’t interact with other users, without knowing why. Other users never see them, but that user doesn’t know that. In the end they’ll simply leave, since they’re not getting anything out of participating in the site.

**Think of *not commenting* as a form of shadowbanning.**

(Which, to clarify, is a *good* thing. We don't want those users, and we don't want to interact with them in any way.)

If you interact with the user, especially in a snarky way, they have something to hang their hat on and react to, be angry about, fight back against. If you simply let their post wither on the vine and die, they get zero out of taking their time to post it; not even the satisfaction of having something or someone to be angry about. It’s a lot subtler, but ultimately more satisfying methinks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your point. First, SO tells us to be nicer, then moderators start to delete comments more aggressiv and ban people for leaving borderline snarky comments. And final you complain that we users do not comment enough?? I'm know to be a big supporter of the whole be nice/CoC thing, but the way it is enforced now is really not nice anymore...

Comment: I'm complaining that users don't comment enough?! Where am I doing that? Quite the opposite.

Comment: I read your answers as being a call against shadowbanning. And you directly say that not commenting is a form of shadowbanning. Maybe I got that wrong, but my conclusion is that you want us to comment more in order to not shadowban users.

Comment: Oh, no, quite the opposite. Sorry if that was unclear. I'm saying rather than engage with unpleasant users in an unpleasant way, simply "shadowban" them and let them drop out of the system. *"If you can't say anything nice, just don't say anything."*

Comment: Ok, then a big sorry from my side. I really read it as if you were arguing that shadowbanning is a bad thing and shouldn't happen.

Comment: It works fine if such questions gets deleted quickly. Worse comes if someone attempts to answer it. AFAIK negative reaction to such answers is considered not welcoming. 'And little makes me sadder than comments on answers saying, “Don’t answer questions like this – it encourages them.' https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Comment: agree @TadeuszKopec - attempts at answers in homework dumps break all the magic of shadowbanning ([recent (sad) example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52483170/839601) - note how desperately accepted answer carefully prevents it from all kinds of automatic deletion)

Comment: @Tadeusz I agree, but I would err on the side of *not punishing answerers.* Jeez, they're taking their time trying to help someone, let's give them a charitable interpretation and not punish them for attempting to help. They'll probably learn over time what questions it's worth investing into and which ones to leave aside when their time investment is being greeted by their answers being removed when the question is being deleted. **Deleting crap questions** is the top priority, everything else sorts itself out from there.

Comment: Down-voting and flagging questions without comment are precisely what others are also recommending.  Does shadowbanning mean any more than this?  Does it imply that you target a particular user beyond an individual question?

Comment: @CPerkins No. I just want to frame *not commenting* in a way that you may get your catharsis without causing needless harm.

Comment: @deceze  Got it.  The term just sounds harsher than I think intended.  "Banning" in general is a rather strong word and usually means more than just deleting one question--like chasing a user away for good.  I'm glad that that isn't being encouraged.

Comment: @CPerkins Well, technically, if you've been downvoted enough, the system *will* ban you in some form or another and prevent you from asking more questions. But yes, we should let *the system* handle that, not individuals or mobs.

Comment: @deceze  Yeah, and the system is designed to do that for good reason, but it would be unfortunate though if a particular term encouraged other users to purposefully chase others away.  Without knowing the "well-intentioned" definition, I think a term like shawdowbanning could easily (naively?) be interpreted as targeted/revenge/serial down-voting, something also not allowed and certainly contrary to "be nice".  Others have essentially said the same thing without adding potentially negative jargon.

Comment: Why "shadowban"? The posted question is rude and abusive, the poster should be getting a real ban.

Comment: @Lundin Your definition of "rude and abusive" is… probably not what is intended with that term. _(Words are difficult, man…)_ I can see how you can say that user is trying to abuse naïve SO users into doing their work, but that is not how "abusive" is meant. They're not being _rude_, except in a very abstract sense, so it's not _that_ kind of "rude _and_ abusive".

Comment: @deceze I am well-aware of what many think is the definition of "rude or abusive", or what it was prior to policy changes. The point here is, in the name of the welcome-wagon, that we should expand the term to rude or abusive questions, as proposed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312038/wed-like-your-feedback-on-our-new-code-of-conduct/312167#312167) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372221/584518).

Comment: If we should no longer tolerate rude comments, then of course we should no longer tolerate rude questions either. Goes without saying since we hold questions to a higher quality standard than comments.

Comment: As I wrote then: "Failing to understand why the community views such question as rude, is a failure to understand and deal with the root of the problem. This is where a whole lot of friction regarding this topic comes from. People rarely post rude comments out of the blue, they are rude when something upsets them.

If there is no clause about rude questions, SE will once again antagonize the community. "  The last sentence is currently what's happening, on a large scale. As a moderator you can try to solve the problem or be a part of it.

Comment: @Lundin OK, I'm not disagreeing with the basic premise that there are jerks trying to abuse SO for their homework. However, that is still not what those flags are for at the moment. Actual R&A content is somewhat high priority since it tends to affect people's emotions very directly and can lead to a whole lot of unpleasantness. *Bad questions*, however disrespectfully posed, can and should primarily be handled with the standard community voting mechanisms. There's no need for a _moderator_ to jump in there immediately.

Comment: Now, should there be some sort of close-and-delete-and-never-come-back vote reason for being a dick when posting questions? Perhaps, maybe, yes. But don't abuse the existing, rather specific, R&A flags for that. Pretty please.

Comment: You're advocating that we do some sort of crowd sourced shadow ban against users like this? Isn't that a bit harsh? I mean, I get it nobody can pin that on anyone as being unwelcoming (the lack of a comment not being actionable and all) but really?

Comment: @Magisch No, I'm saying if it's unsatisfying for you to *not* to leave a comment, ***think of*** not doing so as shadowbanning. Frame the issue differently *for yourself*, so *doing nothing* becomes good enough.

Answer (score 25):

In The Philippines, it's common for family to come up behind you while you're eating, use their hand to grab something off your plate, chew it loudly and tell you what condiment you should have used instead.

Coming from the western world, I was ... incredulous the first time that this happened. You simply just don't *do* something so presumptuous *anywhere in the world* .. wait .. *do you?* It turns out that yes, you do. In many cultures outside of the US & Europe merely *asking* for nearly *anything* isn't presumptuous or imposing at all, as long as you're fully prepared to accept no for an answer quickly.

This helped me gain some insight into the kinds of quality issues we started having when the world initially flooded in not  long after the public beta began. As a moderator, I got *considerably less* annoyed by having that outsider's perspective - these folks didn't *mean* to impose, it just didn't occur to them that they had.

#### So, to answer your question, you have two options:

1. Downvote, vote to close, move on. Nothing else needs to be said. Sometimes 'be nice' comes in the form of "don't be rude."
2. You *can* say "This is just asking too much" along with any parting advice you'd like to give, e.g. "try searching for .... "

What you *shouldn't* do is assume the person had ill-intentions. Maybe they were just looking for where to take the first bite and failed to indicate what they actually wanted. The thing is, you don't know.

Now, if the question started like:

> Okay you fools, solve this stuff for me, and it better shine and get me a great grade!

... that's abusive, and warrants a flag (and a nice moderator talking-to).

But don't infer the second automatically, rude, presumptuous impositions don't look the same across the globe.

Comment: You know, I've started to look forward to answers by you or Shog because eloquence of your writing. Aptly explained.

Comment: So this case boils down to a failure to communicate expectations accordingly. Also, nice answer.

Comment: Man, Filipinos are *rude!* Oh wait, was there some other takeaway? ;o)

Comment: Rude? Nah, they're the most relaxed people in the world. They're also significantly better at eating than pretty much everyone else.

Comment: Koreans and Japanese are also strong contestants in that arena. 

Comment: Well, each new user has to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice and click on  " thanks, I will keep these tips in mind when asking" before asking any question. If asker comes from culture of ignoring what others say then answering is pointless.

Comment: *If asker comes from culture of ignoring what others say...* @TadeuszKopec You mean like accepting the Terms and Conditions without actually reading them?

Comment: "as long as you're fully prepared to accept no for an answer quickly" But basically none of the people asking bad questions are in fact prepared for that.  They just get upset and angry when they don't get an answer, or when someone tells them that their question is problematic.  People that handle it well are rare (mostly because people that respond well to such statements tend to be the type of people that ask good questions).

Comment: This wasn't a culture clash, it was a homework dump. I'm pretty sure that asking others to do one's homework is a big NO in almost every culture.

Comment: Educated liberal Western European culture does not approve of misogyny and racism. We don't allow those here. I'm pretty sure some members of other cultures could engage in unacceptable but somewhat subtle  misogyny or racism without realising they were doing something "rude". Yet we would not give them a pass, would we? If all social groups have a set of social norms they expect members of conform to, and those norms are not universal, should SO be afraid to have Western European liberal norms?

Answer (score 15):

**Come vent on Meta!**

We all get it, such a question is horrible. It hurts our feelings, when such an uncaring OP shows their contempt for the wider community by dumping their homework in our lap.

Retaliation, however, is not an answer. Down vote, vote to close, vote to delete but do not leave an angry comment.

**Come vent on Meta!**

Yes, the OP could use a good scolding; however a good scolding is delivered in private, by an authority figure. A peer taking it upon themselves to publicly lynch another is a vigilante:

- their action is unlikely to be well received by the target: *"Who do you think you are to tell me what I can and cannot do?"*
- their action is unlikely to be well perceived by the larger public: *"Traveler beware, here begins a no-man's land where lone cowboys roam and enforce their ideals at gun point."*

So, how do you get rid of all this frustration and anger building up inside you?

**Come vent on Meta!**

You'll find a sympathetic ear: we've been there, we've felt your frustration, we've felt your anger, we can empathize and pat your back as you rant and grieve and cry.

Come here, you'll feel better.

**Come vent on Meta!**

Answer (score 7):

Honestly, I don't know either what to do. Many answers here are talking about "these type of users" and that we don't want them, and that they don't listen to feedback. My opinion though is that that's a generalization, and could be wrong. There are certainly some indications, such as:

- The user blatantly copy-pasted his homework assignment
- The user didn't format his question to follow the SO guidelines

However, we cannot say for sure that this user won't listen to feedback, nor is willing to edit his question into shape. So, what should we do?

1. Downvote the question and move on? The issue with that is that users in some cases have no clue why they're being downvoted. This could be perceived as unwelcome, as you can see in [a blogpost from a user](https://kristofk.com/response-to-stack-overflow-being-unwelcoming/):

   > And the community came at me and the question got downvoted to -6 and I got a few useless comments. I did get a good answer at the end and I believe that that guy went above and beyond for me.
   >
   > ...
   >
   > As to the downvotes, I have no clue what purpose they serve. One thing is for sure the -6 score on my account has nearly got me banned. **And the cherry on top is that after all this I didn’t learn anything**.
2. Another alternative is to to downvote the question and leave a comment addressing the issues in his question. Sure, we're [encouraged to add a comment when downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes), but since downvotes are part of the moderation process, and we don't want to slow that process down, [they aren't mandatory, for a good reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin).
3. We could downvote, and vote to close the question so that it gets closed and the user receives a canned response, in the format of a close reason. However, considering [all problems with the close vote review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science), there's no guarantee that the question will get closed, and thus there is no guarantee that the user won't perceive it as being unwelcome.
4. We could downvote, and add a predefined, canned response (like the one T.J. Crowder used) as to limit the time spent on moderating the questions. However, if I'm not mistaken, those canned comments can also be perceived as unwelcoming.

There are a lot of potential solutions, such as:

1. deceze [commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374526/be-nice-be-nice-be-nice-yes-but-what-if-the-question-is-horrifically-egregio/374537?noredirect=1#comment633196_374537) about having a more helpful UX/UI when being downvoted, which would help a lot:

   > I agree that misunderstanding downvotes is a big reason why people feel "unwelcome". That is something SO needs to fix by better UI/UX. For example with "you have just received your first downvote, here's what this might mean…" messages or such. Let's work on discussing that. Let's not waste our resources explaining this again and again individually.
2. Another solution would be the one Tim described in [this question about having welcoming, but canned responses to certain situations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371410/can-we-have-some-site-approved-canned-comments-to-match-the-new-coc-and-welcomin). Having canned, but welcoming comments for these situations would also work.
3. Shog9 recently described a solution to low quality questions that would both improve moderation and add a comment to request edits. Which can be found in his reaction to [Should "Very Low Quality" flags be offloaded entirely to tag experts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374490).

However, these are proposals only. At this moment I feel like there is no solution that is both welcoming and doesn't hurt the moderation process, so just like you I'm confused about what to do.

Comment: At the very least, *don't be rude.* Bite your tongue. If you can't say anything positive, say nothing. Do your duty to moderate, help positively when you can, keep down the negativity, however tempting it is. The only way we'll make everyone "feel welcome" is if we give them the answers they came here for. Since that is not something we can do for each and everyone, there's no way a certain percentage won't feel "unwelcome". Just try not to add insult to injury.

Comment: "Do your duty to moderate" @deceze, it is not anyone duty except SO employees. All other do it voluntarily because they want to keep this site clean. And it is upsetting to see that their attitude is the main concern of SO staff, not the amount of litterers.

Comment: I actually see great potential in point 3. The possibility to delete a post, explaining why, without any future comments posted until the OP actually edits the post (hence try to fix it). Both the people moderating have a powerful tool and OP has the possibility to fix the issue in peace if they like the post to stay on SO.

Comment: @PetterFriberg You're right, no clue why I forgot about that post when I posted my answer as both the moderation process would benefit from it (quicker deletion) and the OP would benefit from it (clear feedback as to what can be improved). Now let's hope Shog9 can push this through, and as for now I guess I'll just keep doing what I was doing, no matter how (un)welcoming it is or how fast/slow.

Comment: I sadly have often just stopped commenting, since I'm in low-traffic I just downvote (so it will roomba), it's often to hard to try and close. This is sad because the end result is probably less welcoming (just a -1 and no comment) for a "normal" person.

Comment: We need to organize something in support of shog's proposal

Comment: @Magisch I'm pushing links to that post in every place I can :)... but yes I agree, SE after this new welcoming stuff, needs to give us something so we can feel that we are welcoming.

Comment: "However, we cannot say for sure that this user won't listen to feedback, nor is willing to edit his question into shape."
Well, we now that new user before asking gets this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice and has to click on "thanks, I will keep these tips in mind when asking". I think that looking how much one cared about already provided info is quite a good indicator how future feedback will be treated.

Comment: It should be "we know" not "we now", but I noticed it too late and cannot edit.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec In my opinion there is a difference between ignoring advice posted on a question and not reading a wall of text like like many people do when they "read" and "accept" a website their terms & conditions or privacy policy.

Comment: Tadeusz nailed it. I started to regularly go on "help and improvement". I always leave a comment to the OP when I think that it is mandatory that the OP is enhancing the question (to make answer-able). Maybe 1 out 10 says "thank you". Maybe 1 out of 20 asks me how to improve his input. The rest does nothing. These people want quick answers, and when they don't get that, they shrug shoulders and walk away. They ignored all initial information, and they give zero zip nada about anything that isn't a solution to their problems.

Comment: @GhostCat My answer is about those 1 out of 20, and that we don't know beforehand if the OP is one of those 19/20 or the rare 1/20.

Comment: @deceze Of course people are expected to not be rude, but people are *not* expected to "only say positive things".  It's extremely helpful to tell someone what problems their question has.  It is not inappropriate to give that information.  You're of course not *obligated* to, but creating a community in which people are forbidden from providing constructive criticism is *extremely* harmful, as that's a very important part of a healthy community, especially one centered around programming in which it's so often important to know when you're doing something wrong.

Comment: "we cannot say for sure that this user won't listen to feedback": in almost all cases the homework questions are more advanced than you would ask a 13 year old.  So the asker has already been through many years of schooling, but has not learned of the value of doing homework yourself. I doubt a few comments on SO will change their attitude.

Comment: @Raedwald As you've said yourself, it happens "in **almost** all cases, and you **doubt** it will help change hteir attitude". I'm just not sure whether we should tailor our responses to the 99%, and losing the 1% who would listen due to feeling unwelcome, or should we tailor our responses to the 1%, which would cost a lot more time to us. Personally, I try to assume that everyone is doing their best, and I try to approach everyone like that. So in the case of a homework question, I assume that my comment may make a difference. Feel free to call me naïve though.

Answer (score 2):

Flag as `too broad` or `unclear what you are asking` and move on.

Question is why it is allowed to post a 'question' without a single questionmark in the text.

Comment: There might be edge cases where a question mark isn't needed. But a downvote is required on that question - a close vote is not enough.

Comment: @S.L. Sure, a literal question mark isn't always necessary. *"When I do this I get that error"* – we all know what the implied question is here. But when confronted with a *dump of requirements*, then the only possible reaction can be "OK, so what issue do you have with this?"

Comment: @S.L.Barth not sure why you would waste rep with a downvote on that question. A flag is sufficient here IMHO.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler Downvoting questions is free; only downvoting answers will cost you a point.

Comment: @S.L.Barth huh, never noticed. Thank you :). Ignore my point then, please.

Answer (score 2):

For a start, you are to be heartily commended for two things.

**Firstly, for recognizing that the problem is in yourself.** That's freaking HUGE. That takes really impressive levels of self-awareness, and that can only be a good thing.

**Secondly, for attacking the question, rather than the asker**, at least in the question you have asked here. While some of the attacks (for example, "lazy") do project onto the asker of the attacked question, you at least made a strong effort to distinguish between the two.

---

But that does not answer your whole question.

**"what to do when you run into [...] homework dump questions"** - has been answered by most answers here. This is a reasonably trivial question, with the trivial answer: if we can't say anything nice, then we are *required* to say nothing at all. We don't get to excuse ourselves by saying "it's hard".

**"How to respond nicely to the likes of this?"** is, to me, the far more proactive and provocative question, going to the core of the new "be nice" movement.

So you find a "bad" question. It goes against everything that Stack Overflow stands for. Perhaps a homework question. Or a question where they have given no information. Or off-topic. Or too verbose and filed with irrelevancies like the health of their dog.

But for some reason, you feel you want to respond, and you want to do so in a way that makes Stack Overflow look good, and makes the asker and *everyone else reading their question* feel motivated to support the Stack Overflow community and contribute positively.

My best effort at a helpful, welcoming response would be something like (using the link from S.L Barth's answer here):

"While homework questions are allowed on Stack Overflow, this one doesn't seem to have a specific question. That makes it hard or impossible to answer here, so I'm afraid it's likely to be removed. **But don't lose hope!** There's a resource here on how to get help on homework problems, and how to hone them into high-quality questions that will get answers! https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems. And don't forget the tips at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice too! Welcome to Stack Overflow, and good luck solving your problem."

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just take a break? Do something you like or something you may get paid for?

The flood of low-level question does not seem to be a concern for site owners. If they expect that bad questions should be handled by the standard community voting mechanism, they should take care of it working well. [They don't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314089/what-does-constructive-criticism-of-a-design-change-look-like/314348#314348).

Once there is a sign that the team cares about keeping the site clean (something like [implementing Shog9's suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368875/should-very-low-quality-flags-be-offloaded-entirely-to-tag-experts/374490#374490), voluntarily moderation may be resumed.

Comment: interesting. This reminds of [Close Votes review: I'm going on a strike!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208220/165773) A practical modification of this approach (that has proven to work quite well back then) adjusted to current situation could look about as follows: find a bunch of recent (less than few hours) answered homework dumps, keep them open and use upvotes to push them into [meta-tag:hot-questions] list. If we could gather 10-20 voters angry enough about negligence of quality matters we could probably have some fun with it

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as upvoting carp, but an organized review strike sounds like something interesting to try in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

Would have been a dilemma if you hadn't asked here, but thankfully you did.

While we *should* try to be nice, be polite and be friendly, a more principle thing is to *hold our stance*. When they have a coflict, there needs to be a "precedence" or "priority", and in this case, *our stance*.

Without repeating other answers too much, it's clear that we explicitly dislike these low-quality questions, specifically full assignment/homework dumps. To remain nice, we may stay silent, cast a close vote and move on, leaving the assignment dump behind for automatic deletion.

For me, I wouldn't even bother leaving a comment. It's their right to ask for cheat and take the consequences, and it's also our right to reject their questions. If they come in a bad manner, why would I waste my time telling them that asking others to to their work is bad, when I don't even know who (what kind of persons) they are?

Answer (score -12):

After the policy changes, I have tried to flag questions such as this one as "rude and abusive", since that is exactly what they are. The moderators have declined the flags though and taken no disciplinary actions against the offender.

Therefore we can conclude that being rude and abusive is still tolerated. Which is of course still not an excuse to be rude or snarky in turn.

If someone gets banned for posting a snarky comment to that trash question, while the OP does *not* also get banned... then I don't think SO is a site we should contribute to any longer.

Comment: Would banning OPs of those questions really make any difference? From what I've seen, most of those users only ask one or at most a couple questions and are then gone forever.

Comment: Yeah it does not seem to have sense flagging these, the community can handle them (mods have enough with other stuff), but for sure we would need something like this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374490/563532 so we can spend less effort on them.

Comment: Funny thing, my high-schooler was just given an assignment today about social shaming, and we discussed the topic for a couple of hours.  We found it quite sad how quick people are to judge and not give second chances or allow others to learn and change.  The SO system already handles cases of repeated abuse, so it's not our call to demand this for a single question.  Honestly I find unwillingness to let others learn and keep trying rather rude and abusive.  Does that mean I should campaign to get you completely kicked of SO for this answer?  Of course not!

Comment: @CPerkins Not sure I agree. SO is a high pressure environment, a certain aspect of "watch your step" is already built into the system.

Comment: That is not what "rude and abusive" flags are for. You're interpreting that at a very abstract level, as in *"it is rude not to abide by the community standards"* and *"trying to abuse others into doing their work"*. What R&A flags are *intended* for is vulgarity and verbal attacks against other users. They're somewhat high-priority flags, abusing them for mere crap questions is rude. 

Comment: @deceze Your insinuation of that being rude could be rude, careful not to fall into the circle of rude... :P

Comment: @Magisch They could be making new accounts each time they ask a question, since they aren't committed to the site. Besides, it is more about consistent moderation rules.

Comment: @PetterFriberg The community cannot take disciplinary actions against rude and abusive users.

Comment: @Magisch  I don't follow.  I wonder if my comment was misunderstood.  How does "watch your step" translate into "You made a mistake with one question.  You rude scumbag, we're banning you from SO for good."?  There is no need to get so offended by one question.  It might be ironic that calling someone out for such a bad question can backfire, but other have already given great advise about downvoting and moving on.

Comment: I think the rudest and most complete treatment that is alotted to us as community is to simply close and downvote without dignifying the question with a comment at all. So if you want to make sure the message gets across, that'll certainly do it.

Comment: @CPerkins I was more arguing against the (percieved) point that your comment likened the treatment this question got to social shaming.

Comment: @Magisch  I agree.  I don't think this equals socials shaming exactly, but the unforgiving mentality of wanting to immediately ban someone without any second chance or recourse seems to match the attitude of many knee-jerk social shamers.

Comment: @CPerkins That's not nearly the same thing. Imagine if you enter the supermarket and declare that you are urgently hungry, then demand that the employees fetch food for you, cook it for you, and then you leave without paying. That's not socially acceptable behavior and will have consequences.

Comment: @deceze The flags are being used for mere crap comments, are they not? Do we have higher quality standards on comments than on questions now?

Comment: On questions they carry a severely higher penalty, though. Getting a post spam or r/a deleted will IP block you and make your life really difficult right away. Getting a comment deleted as unwelcoming won't even do jack until a moderator manually decides to.

Comment: @Lundin downvoting and closing questions will get them question banned. True they can get new accounts, but if you catch'em then you mod flag. I don't feel we need mods for these kind of question, instead we need a better system so we can handle them quickly with a comment to op (as in Shog9 suggestion, T.J. Crowder could have deleted it with that comment and Hover would never need to see it)

Comment: @Lundin  Yes, but the consequence should probably be a manager taking the person aside and kindly explaining how shopping works (in the particular place).  The person is either kindly asked to leave or given the chance to immediately about face and go on shopping with the rest of the customers.  There is no need for am immediate vote and call for comments to be had by all employees and other customers whether or not the rude person should be banned.

Comment: @CPerkins As for second chances, you will of course not instantly get a permanent ban. It will have a limited time, after which you are forgiven and welcome back. If you offend again, the next ban will be more severe. This is how bans on SO work. Similarly, users who don't offend in a long time will be completely forgiven.

Comment: @CPerkins Why should the manager do that? It's not their job to educate children and the supermarket is not a place for learning how to behave as a decent human being. That's rather a task for their parents, so that the child may function in society. The people at the supermarket have better things to do, such as taking care of the well-behaving, paying, recurring customers.

Comment: @Lundin  Hmm.  I guess we disagree on a more fundamental level, since I would expect a manager to be responsible for all sorts of details beyond smiling at perfect customers.  My advice at this point, I suggest standing near the tomatoes next time you go shopping, but don't complain to the manager when he expects you to pay for the tomatoes you throw at other rude customers.

Comment: @CPerkins Yeah I would think the manager is responsible for calling security/the police when some rude drunkard is abusing their store. You'll find that this is exactly what they will do if you try it IRL.

Comment: @Lundin IMO, calling the cops is a rather last-resort mechanism if you cannot deal with the situation yourself, e.g. because it's beyond your physical abilities and verbal negotiation doesn't help.

Comment: @deceze Until you get ten rude drunkards per day, seven days per week. You'll soon lose patience and call the cops immediately.

Comment: @Lundin To stop talking in analogies… *everyone* on SO is the cops. The more drunkards there are, the more the enforcement must be spread out. Otherwise the cops will be paralyzed from overwork.

Comment: @deceze Then that's obviously not a good environment for those who are merely programmers. The prerequisites for being a good programmer and being a good cop happen to be very different.

Comment: @Lundin Many problems probably indeed do arise because programmers sometimes aren’t… the most qualified people to deal with social issues, I’ll give you that. 

Comment: @deceze hmm calling programmers social misfits... watch out we have a new CoC :P