# How soon should a bad question be deleted?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-delete

While it's common to close questions that are bad and need to be reworked, sometimes they are also voted to be deleted before there's really any time for the author to even read comments about how to improve the question.

Is there a suitable time to wait before voting to delete a question? Should we show some lenience to at least give the author a chance to read comments and perhaps improve the question?

Giving some time is extra important, IMO, for people new to the site, that are eager to ask their question and perhaps haven't fully read the help pages yet, but will if they are prompted to.

Comment: Depends on how _bad_ the question is, if it's a question that can be edited to be a useful question I usually comment, leave the tab open, and give it about 30 mins, if I've got no response from the asker, then I VTC.

Comment: "How do I fix a tire puncture" should probably be closed+deleted neigh on instantly, as there's no scope to make the question on-topic (apart from asking a totally different one under the same ID), so I guess it depends on how far off-topic/unsalvageable the question is.

Comment: Basically is there any hope that the question can be salvaged? If not then it might as well be deleted sooner rather than later.

Comment: Close asap. Delete if roomba failed.

Comment: Related: [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260263/7795130) (Possible duplicate? Even though it's about closing and this question is about deletion, the reasoning is basically the same.)

Comment: How soon? Possibly [even before closure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368875/should-very-low-quality-flags-be-offloaded-entirely-to-tag-experts/374490#374490).

Comment: _"give the author a chance to read comments and perhaps improve the question"_ Do you know how often improvement actually happens?

Comment: The problem is that if the author is a newbie, he's going to ask his question, wait a bit, and go back.  If it stays alive for a while, he'll get to read the comments and (hopefully) see the errors of his ways - maybe even read the "How do I ask a good question" link.  But, if he goes back and sees that his question has been deleted, he'll just curse the site and never learn how to create an MVCE

Answer (score 32):

As with any kind of vote, we trust that the users casting the votes will use their own judgement.

If three users with 20k rep or more<sup>*</sup> ([the necessary rep level to cast delete votes without having to wait 48hs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/348149)) believe the question can't reasonably be salvaged, the sooner it's deleted the better for everyone. Asker included.

If the question remains closed but not deleted and can't really be edited into shape, it will probably continue to get down-votes, which will count against the question author.

<sub><sup>*</sup> Or just one mod, since they have binding votes and the community elected them to use their mighty mod powers when appropriate</sub>

Comment: Let's note that [on Stack Overflow, our current active mods all have more than 20k rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). Sure, may not always be the case.

Comment: @Cœur You are right, but the point I was trying to make is that 20k or 5k you need only one mod  to delete-vote (instead of three users) since their votes are binding.

Comment: Moderators _can_ delete content immediately, but usually they won't. [Moderators tend to hold off on immediate deletion of questions if there is any hope at all for them to be edited into a good, on topic question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/352252/4099593)

Answer (score 19):

I'm in favour of [removing poor quality content off the site quickly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371071/can-we-decrease-the-roomba-times-for-auto-deletion-of-bad-questions).

People can still read the comments under their deleted question. They can also read the links in the close reason. If a question is really bad, there's no real reason to keep it on the site. People can flag to have it reopened. This way, if the post hasn't been downvoted, it will be off the front page. Three downvotes to remove it from the front page. Which is not in itself a reason to downvote. By deleting the post, it gives the user a chance to edit without more downvotes.

There is one caveat. When there's ongoing discussion in the comments helping the OP.

If I delete a closed question on a new user account, I usually leave a custom comment.

> Please raise a mod flag to have your question undeleted if you edit it to be on topic. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 8):

If the question is closed and will roomba, I'd say that there's no need to delete it. If the question is very bad and downvotes are piling on, let OP decide to delete it.

If the question is edited in the meanwhile, let it follow the reopen process.

One reason why a closed question should be deleted would be if it doesn't roomba because of answers for poor questions:

- useless/nth time duplicates
- too broad/unclear with guesswork answer, which is accepted.

Those aren't helping future readers, encourage people to waste their time to answer (and get ill-gotten reputation for that, see [What to do when a high rep user answers a low-quality, off-topic or duplicate question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315936/what-to-do-when-a-high-rep-user-answers-a-low-quality-off-topic-or-duplicate-qu)), they should be deleted after the "legal" time (which is 2 days after closure, so people have to keep track of that or install the necessary tools).

One exception would be a very bad/off-topic question which is (for unknown reasons) being reopened without the necessary editing. 20k+ users/moderators could decide to stop this and delete the question  (as you know, a -3 score question (or less) can be deleted immediately by 20k users)